# String substitution in large file

Tags: scripting

I have two TSV (*tab separated value*) files -- `file_A.txt` and `file_B.txt`

`file_A.txt` contains two columns -- `A_ID`, `A_Name`

`file_B.txt` contains 4 columns -- `B_ID1`, `B_Name1`, `B_ID2`, `B_Name2`

Need to go through each `A_ID`, if it matches `B_ID1` or `B_ID2`, replace `B_Name1` or `B_Name2` with `A_Name` accordingly.

I am looking for a way to do it efficiently since `file_B` is few hundred MB.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How big is `fileA` ?

Comment: "a few hundred MB" isn't all that large.  Just about anything should be able to handle that okay...

Comment: Bash is easy to hack together but very slow at processing. I've done similar things (search and replace) on similar sized files (couple thousand lines) and it works. If you're keen then you can make something in C(++) and you'll see a dramatic speed improvement of maybe 50x to 100x.

Comment: Have you actually tried any of the "standard" solutions such as `awk -vOFS=\\t 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}; $1 in a {$2=a[$1]}; $3 in a {$4=a[$3]}; {print}' file_A.txt file_B.txt`

Comment: if possible, go for any light weight db.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the substitutions in file_B.txt format, as Spike suggested, a light weight db like sqlite could do this.

The following would read file_A.txt and file_B.txt into a transient in-memory database and output the results to the TSV file `MODIFIED-file_B.txt`

```
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' << EOF  > MODIFIED-file_B.txt
CREATE TABLE a ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name );
.import file_A.txt a
CREATE TABLE b (id1 INTEGER,name1 TEXT,id2 INTEGER,name2 TEXT);
.import file_B.txt b
SELECT b.id1,
       ifnull((SELECT name from a WHERE a.id=b.id1),b.name1),
       b.id2, 
       ifnull((SELECT name from a WHERE a.id=b.id2),b.name2)
FROM b;
EOF
```

This reads each file into a separate table then outputs the b table with your A substitutions, if available, otherwise returns the original B_name.

If memory usage is a concern you can run it with a filename e.g. `sqlite3 -separator $'\t' temporary.db` to create a scratch file.